# How to identify of this connector used by TinyCircuits batteries?

Tags: connector, identification

I want to buy some replacement batteries and the best priced ones come with bare wires. I would therefore need to attach my own connector to the end.

What is the name if this type of connector and how can I go about identifying this one specifically (which parts do I measure)? I will also need the metal clips that attach to the wires. What are those called and what kind if tool would I need to attach them?

[image]

Comment: That type of battery is often supplied with some form of connector from JST, which might help you find it.

Comment: Unless you're doing a lot of these, your best bet might be to spend extra money for the pre-installed connectors. The crimping tools can be expensive. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/158725/38335) for general information on how to crimp/assemble similar connectors.

Answer (score 4):

This is a 1mm pitch micro JST "SH" connector (part number SHR-02V-S-B) and [is available from DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/SHR-02V-S-B/455-1377-ND/759866).

SH is the name of a [specific series](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/sh-series/8406?mpart=SHR-02V-S-B&vendor=455) of connectors by [JST Sales America, Inc.](http://www.jst.com/)

Comment: SH stands for Super Hard to disconnect without breaking them.

Comment: @Passerby So true!  I often use a tiny flat-bladed screwdriver to work these out to avoid ripping the wires from the terminals.

Comment: I couldn't fit even my smallest precision flat head in there to free the cable. I ended up having to use an x-acto knife to get in there and pull away locking mechanism. I wonder if there is an easier way.